# Does a plugged in 12v usb-charger use energy when no device is connected?

Tags: charger, 12v, usb-hub

I hard-wired a 12v cigarette-plug into my a-pillar.

The whole point is to have an additional phone charger on the leftside where my phone mostly sits.

I connected it directly to the battery ( with a fuse ), so I can use it when the engine is off aswell.

When I connected the usb-charger to the cigarette-12v-plug an indicator-light came on. ( nothing else is connected ).

So obviously this is using power.

1. Will this drain my battery?
2. Do 12V usb-charger without an inidicator light use power when nothing else is connected?
3. if #2 is negative, how can i solve this?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes.

Comment: I suggest putting a switch (relay or transistor) in series with the charger and connecting the power of that to something that comes on with the ignition (air con/radio). Such when the is off, the thing is disconnected. Just an idea. FYI obviously when the ignition is off and your device is still on it's draining power. If you drive the vehicles everyday for a decent distance the non driving loss may be compensated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) yes, how long that will take depends on how much it draws and how long between car uses.

2) yes, they use power, more or less depends on the design & quality

3) Solve it by powering it from a fused accessory feed or ignition feed.

And, personally, I would do 3 whatever the power it draws...

Answer (score 0):

A similar question would be: 'what's the mileage of my car?'. Depends on your car, obviously.

So in this case: depends on the design. It could draw several µA up to several 10's of mA. Pretty simple to measure actually, then you'll know the answer you're looking for immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Will this drain my battery?

All Standard manufacturers use ultra-low power Standby controllers - which results in a very low power consumption.

2. Do 12V usb-charger without an indicator light use power when nothing else is connected?

yes. here there is an led for visual indication (in regular variants there will be no led)

3. if #2 is negative, how can i solve this?

connect it after the Fuse Box